# How to avoid the ajax done click in this case

Tags: jquery

Initially during page load I am making an AJAX call and once it completes I am raising a `click` event for showing default data for the `1D` tab. If the user presses the `1W` tab while the data for `1D` is loading how can I avoid the done call present under the initial AJAX call? This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    doAjaxcallfordatafetch();

    $("ul.menu li").click(function() {
        var tabclicked = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        doAjaxcallfordatafetch(tabclicked);
    });
    $("ul.menu li a:first").click();
});

function doAjaxcallfordatafetch(tabclicked) {
    // doing an ajax call and once ajax call completes (done call)
    // i am doing $("ul.menu li a:first").click();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gr1L23us/11/

Comment: Why bother with the `click()` at all? Just make the div visible for `1D` by default and load the data in to it.

Comment: yes seems a nice solution , thanks a lot....